# How to check ImageField is empty

Tags: django, imagefield

I have an ImageField in my model and when I'm saving it I want to check that if it's None or not.

In django shell I'm calling my object's ImageField and it gives :

```
>>> p.avatar
<ImageFieldFile: None>
>>> p.avatar is None
False
```

I found that the ImageField's name is u'', so is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

> I found that the ImageField's name is
>   u'', so is there any better way to do
>   it ?

Actually, it looks like that's exactly how this class evaluates `bool()`, so the better way is to just test its `bool()` by calling `if p.avatar`

`ImageFieldFile` subclasses `File`, which defines:

```
def __nonzero__(self):
    return bool(self.name)
```

So the better way is indeed:

```
if not p.avatar:
   print "I don't exist"

bool(p.avatar) is False
```

Comment: On template, you should test {% p.avatar != '' %}. Ugly but it works...

Comment: not necessary, you can test simply with `{% if p.avatar %}` ... `{% endif %}`