# Queryset of models without valid ImageField

Tags: django

I have a feeling [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213025/how-to-check-imagefield-is-empty) is something to do with the answer, but I'm wondering how get a queryset that contains null imagefields?

Doing something like:

```
 Model.objects.filter(model_image__isnull=True)
```

Doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgresql when there is no image field looks like '', so I use

```
Model.objects.filter(model_image='')
```